# MySQL query to only select parent record with ALL options from child table NOT some

Tags: mysql

I am struggling to write a query to retrieve cars with both 'allows' and 'cd player'. It seems my query returns cars with one or the other but not only those with both. Here is how to recreate my problem:

```
    create database `car_sales`;
    use `car_sales`;
    create table car (
        `id` int(11) not null primary key auto_increment,
        `make` varchar(255) not null,
        `model` varchar(255) not null
    );

    create table `option` (
        `id` int(11) not null primary key auto_increment,
        `car_id` int(11) not null,
        `name` varchar(255) not null,
        foreign key (`car_id`) references car(id),
        index(`name`)
    );

    insert into car (`id`,`make`,`model`) values(1,'ford','focus');
    insert into car (`id`,`make`,`model`) values(2,'tesla','P85D');
    insert into car (`id`,`make`,`model`) values(3,'totoya','corolla');
    insert into car (`id`,`make`,`model`) values(4,'volkswagon','polo');

    insert into `option`(`car_id`,`name`) values(1,'arcon');
    insert into `option`(`car_id`,`name`) values(1,'alloys');

    insert into `option`(`car_id`,`name`) values(2,'cd player');
    insert into `option`(`car_id`,`name`) values(2,'arcon');
    insert into `option`(`car_id`,`name`) values(2,'alloys');

    insert into `option`(`car_id`,`name`) values(3,'leather');
    insert into `option`(`car_id`,`name`) values(3,'sunroof');
    insert into `option`(`car_id`,`name`) values(3,'alloys');

    insert into `option`(`car_id`,`name`) values(4,'electric windows');
    insert into `option`(`car_id`,`name`) values(4,'cd player');
```

Then I execute the following query which returns results with at least one of the features but not both:

```
select c.*,o.* from car c left join `option` o on (c.id=o.car_id) having o.name in ('alloys','cd player');
```

Please help me adjust this query so I get only cars with both features!

Comment: Replace the having condition with `WHERE o.name='alloys' OR o.name='cd player'`

Comment: @leonardo_palma that didn't work, got the exact same result from > select c.*,o.* from car c left join `option` o on (c.id=o.car_id) where  o.name ='alloys' or o.name='cd player';

Comment: Perhaps you need an inner join instead of a left join? [Joins explained](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Comment: Sorry, you have to put AND instead of OR.

Comment: @leonardo_palma I had tried that and that returns no results when it should return the tesla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a left join, since the results must have the 2 options.

```
select make, model
from car c
join `option` o on (c.id = o.car_id)
where name in ('alloys','cd player')
group by make, model having count(*) = 2
;
```

I would highly recommend not using a mysql keyword(option) as a table name.

Comment: Thanks @JRD, this returned the expected result. The columns names I used here are not the ones from my actual solution, was just trying to make  them simple to understand within the context of the problem :-)